# What caused the momentum for EU directives on blind-spots of vehicles in the last 20 years

Tags: european-union, law, transportation

During the last 20 years European laws on blind-spots, areas of road the driver cannot see, have become more strict.
The original directive is from 1971 (71/127/EEG). But then there are changes in 2003 and in 2009. In 2022 new trucks will have to improve their view (make their blind-spot smaller) and in 2024 the new rules will apply to all trucks, not just new ones.

What has caused this development? Was there a successful international lobby-campaign? And how did it come about?

(Blind spots on trucks are huge and terrifying: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2cr5A_R87iU)

Comment: Comments deleted. Please remember that comments are not for answering the question. If you would like to answer, please post a real answer which adheres to our quality standards.

Comment: I don't have data to back it up on hand, but I believe truck blind spots are the underlying reason for a significant proportion of traffic accidents and it is an issue with a technological solution which tends to be much easier to solve than say curbing drunk driving.

Comment: @quarague that is absolutely true, but it is still strange when compared to the laws for electric cars, for example only *new* electric cars have to make sound as of this summer while existing electric cars can continue to run in stealth mode causing unnecessary accidents running over with pedestrians and cyclists. Here too the statistics are clear and the technological solutions are quite easy.